# Problem Launching web server using AWS CLI using on MAC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

```
I am in the early stages in Learning AWS. i face this problem when trying to Launch web server using AWS CLI using on MAC
I'm doing this to connect to the ec2 instance in created.
After running the command
# Set the Region
AZ=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability- zone`
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${AZ::-1}
# Obtain latest Linux AMI

#AMI=$(aws ssm get-parameters --names /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux- latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2 --query
```

'Parameters[0].https://forums.aws.amazon.com /' --output text) echo $AMI
# end
I GET THIS MESSAGE

```
Provided region_name '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>404 - Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
</body>
</html' doesn't match a supported format.

any suggestions?
```

Comment: Your question lacks details and relevant info. What exactly are you doing? How exactly did you setup your web server?

Comment: Hi Marcin, I'm trying  use AWS CLI to communicate with the EC2 service.

Comment: What AWS CLI are you using? Can you provide example? What is your Ec2 service?

Comment: I just  launched An Instance in AWS EC2. 
USING The command Line on Mac O/S trying to connect to the EC2 SERVER but i get this problem

Comment: Specifically, what did you type to launch the EC2 instance?  Specifically, what did you type to produce the output in the original message?  (Feel free to edit/update the original message.)

Comment: Hi Mark J. I updated the question .Please kindly read through again and if you can  suggest something i can do .

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner l think you should also consider learning how to launch instances using the AWS console before diving into the CLI.

You may have a look at this guide, which guides you step by step on how to launch your instance using the console considering all the  necessary
requirements :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html

After that it will be easy for you to use the CLI :https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-ec2-instances.html

You can also use the link above to help you troubleshoot your error.
Hopefully this will help :)